# Material on the analysis of (micro)array data

Tags: proteins, statistics, biostatistics

I'm at the moment analyzing cytokine array data. The available material on the statistical analysis of these data is more than unsatisfactory. Since a lot of effort is being made in the analysis of gene microarray and MALDI-TOF proteome data, I seek to apply these methods on my cytokine arrays.

**What is a good introductory text on microarray analysis, especially quality control and error estimation?**

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start would be [Statistical Methods for Microarray Data Analysis](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-60327-337-4/page/1). I'd also suggest papers from the labs of [Terry Speed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%28%28speed+t%5bAuthor%5d%29+AND+review%5bPublication+Type%5d%29+AND+microarray), [Gary Churchill](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%28%28churchill%20ga%5bAuthor%5d%29%20AND%20review%5bPublication%20Type%5d%29%20AND%20microarray), [John Quackenbush](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%28%28quackenbush+j%5bAuthor%5d%29+AND+review%5bPublication+Type%5d%29+AND+microarray), and [Gordon Smyth](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%28Smyth+GK%5bAuthor%5d%29+AND+microarray).

Also, I found some papers that specifically reflect on your exact issue: how to apply the methods developed for DNA microarrays to analyze protein arrays.

- [Eckel-Passow *et al.* Experimental design and analysis of antibody microarrays: applying methods from cDNA arrays. *Cancer Res.* 2005 Apr 15;65(8):2985-9.](http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/65/8/2985.long)
- [Royce *et al.* Extrapolating traditional DNA microarray statistics to tiling and protein microarray technologies. *Methods Enzymol.* 2006;411:282-311.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687906110150#)